# Can't use base class template member function

Tags: c++, c++14

For some reason, I can see the top most `template<typename T> X<...>::fn(T&&)`, but not the base class versions.  Importing them using the `using` keyword doesn't work.  As I understand it:

> ## [In Class definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration)
>
> [... If the derived class already has a member with the same name, parameter list, and qualifications, the derived class member hides or overrides (doesn't conflict with) the member that is introduced from the base class.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration)

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

#define ENABLE_IF(...) std::enable_if_t<__VA_ARGS__, int> = 0

struct dummy {};

template<typename T>
struct always_false : std::false_type {};

template<typename...Ts>
struct X;

template<typename Tx, typename T, typename...Ts>
struct X<Tx, T, Ts...> : X<Tx, Ts...>
{
    using X<Tx, Ts...>::fn;

    template<typename R, ENABLE_IF(std::is_same<T, R>::value)>
    auto fn(R&& x)
    {
        return x;
    }
};

template<typename Tx>
struct X<Tx>
{
    template<typename R>
    auto fn(R&& x)
    {
        static_assert(always_false<R>::value, "Invalid type");
    }
};

int main()
{
    X<dummy, int, float> x;
    std::cout << x.fn(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << x.fn(1.f) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}
```

I've tried this on g++, clang and VC++ and they all have various errors, ([ambiguous call](http://rextester.com/NVNAR27766), [member function disabled](http://rextester.com/DRORO17547) and [could not deduce](http://rextester.com/JCNGK75919)).  It's interesting to note that g++ is failing on the call to `X<dummy, int, float>::fn(int&&)`, whereas clang and VC++ are failing on calling `X<dummy, int, float>::fn(float&&)`.

As I understand it, the compiler should ignore the absolute base class member function `template<typename R> R X<dummy>::fn(R&&)` when calling `X<dummy, int, float>::fn(float&&)`, because that template should resolve to `float X<dummy>::fn(float&&)` which is an exact match to derived member function `float X<dummy, float>::fn(float&&)` requiring the derived one to be called without ambiguity.

What am I doing wrong?  What am I not understanding?

## Edit

To paraphrase [T.C.'s answer so far](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42919312/1366368), "this is what the spec says", which I would say is not the correct interpretation.  The two points given there are in conflict with each other.  If they are an equally good match (point 1), then only the most derived function signature should be visible (point 2).

Anyway, if the problem is a spec problem, then it should go away if I were to disable the possibility of a matching overload which would result in an ambiguity.  Thus the following should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

#define ENABLE_IF(...) std::enable_if_t<__VA_ARGS__, int> = 0


template<typename T>
struct always_false : std::false_type {};


template<typename...Ts>
struct list {};


template<typename...Ts>
struct is_one_of;

template<template <typename...> class TT, typename T, typename T1, typename...Ts>
struct is_one_of<T, TT<T1, Ts...>> : is_one_of<T, TT<Ts...>> {};

template<template <typename...> class TT, typename T, typename...Ts>
struct is_one_of<T, TT<T, Ts...>> : std::true_type {};

template<template <typename...> class TT, typename T>
struct is_one_of<T, TT<>> : std::false_type {};


template<typename...Ts>
struct X;

template<typename L, typename T, typename...Ts>
struct X<L, T, Ts...> : X<L, Ts...>
{
    using X<L, Ts...>::fn;

    template<typename R, ENABLE_IF(std::is_same<T, R>::value)>
    constexpr auto fn(R&& x) const
    {
        return x;
    }
};

template<typename L>
struct X<L>
{
    template<typename R, ENABLE_IF(!is_one_of<R, L>::value)>
    constexpr auto fn(R&& x) const
    {
        static_assert(always_false<R>::value, "Type R didn't match");
    }
};


template<typename...Ts>
struct XX : X<list<Ts...>, Ts...> {};

int main()
{
    XX<int, float> x;
    std::cout << x.fn(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << x.fn(2.f) << std::endl;
}
```

It does work under [g++](http://rextester.com/CSRVT88032), but has the same problems under [clang](http://rextester.com/BXYCU90298) and [VC++](http://rextester.com/FZLC83039).  So, is g++ the only one that is conforming here and the rest are defective?

Comment: Since enable_if_t is only templated on two things, I am not sure why you defined the macro variadically.

Comment: @NirFriedman, the reason is because there could be a comma which would make the macro think that there is more than one parameter.

Comment: @T.C. What do I need to do for #2?  I want the base class member functions to be hidden.

Comment: @T.C., but it is.  See updated question and [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42917855/cant-use-base-class-template-member-function?noredirect=1#comment73099932_42919312) on your question.

Comment: @T.C., well, if I'm incorrect that when a base and derived class have a member function that results in the same sig (excluding the template parameters and return type), that only the derived will be made visible when using the `using base::member_function` syntax, then please enlighten me.  It would seem pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1. Your baseline catch-all version of `fn` is an equally good match as the other `fn` varieties; therefore at best you'll get an ambiguous overload error.
2. Hiding for *using-declaration*s does not consider the full signature (which for function templates would include the template parameter list). It [only considers](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/namespace.udecl#15) 1) name, 2) (function) parameter-type-list, 3) cv-qualification, and 4) *ref-qualifier* (if any). If all four match, the base class function template is hidden and not brought in by the *using-declaration*. Notably, the template parameter list is not considered. In your case, the only thing different between the various `fn`s is the template parameter list; they all have the same name, same parameter-type-list, same cv-qualification, and same ref-qualifier (or lack thereof). Therefore, the most derived `fn` will hide all `fn`s from the base classes.

   GCC appears to not implement this part to spec and consider the template parameter list when deciding on hiding.

   One possible fix for this part is to move the `enable_if` to a function parameter, which *is* considered by the hiding check.

---

The way overload resolution in C++ works is:

1. Name lookup to build a set of candidate functions and function templates.
2. For each candidate function template, perform template argument deduction. If deduction fails, remove it from the overload set. If deduction succeeds, replace the candidate function template with the deduced specialization.
3. Eliminate non-viable candidates from the set of candidates.
4. If the set is empty, error. Otherwise, find the best viable function in the candidates.

Hiding operates at the first step: if a declaration is hidden, it is not found by name lookup, and therefore it is not in the initial set of candidates and will not be considered by overload resolution *under any circumstance*, regardless of what happens in step 2, 3, or 4. A hidden declaration effectively doesn't exist for the purposes of overload resolution.

So, in your case, the base class `fn`s are all hidden. What does it mean? It means that the only candidate found by name lookup is the `int` one from the most derived class, nothing else. If template argument deduction and substitution succeed, that function template will be called. If they fail (as in the `x.fn(2.f)` case), then there is no viable candidate left, and you get an error.

Comment: Why wouldn't it consider the resulting instantiated function signature (excluding the template parameter list)?  That doesn't sound intuitive or useful.

Comment: I want the base functions with the same sig (excluding the template sig) to be hidden.  In the first example, `X<dummy, int, float>`'s member function `fn` signature is `float(float&&)`.  It's base class's sig would be `int(int&&)` and the final base class's sig would be anything that would match `template<typename T> T(T&&)`.  When attempting to call `X<dummy, int, float>::fn(1.f)`, then there should be two matches, `float X<dummy, float>::fn(float&&)` and `float X<dummy>::fn(float&&)` (when template is instantiated).  I'm saying, because they are the same, the base should be hidden and...

Comment: ... should only match on `float X<dummy, float>::fn(float&&)`.  This is what I want and based on your point 2, is what should happen.  My understanding is that your point 1 is not correct, *because* of your point 2.

Comment: Interesting... the [link](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/namespace.udecl#15) you posted seems to state otherwise.  `member functions and member function templates in the derived class override and/or hide member functions and member function templates with the same name, `[parameter-type-list](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct#def:parameter-type-list)`, cv-qualification`. parameter-type-list points to a link which states: `...After producing the list of parameter types...forming the function type. The resulting list...is the function's parameter-type-list`, inferring that...

Comment: @Adrian You realize that function templates have parameter-type-lists too, even before substitution?

Comment: They might, but that document clearly states that the definition of parameter-type-list, in the context stated, is the resulting list, not before.  Which, IMO, makes more sense.

Comment: @Adrian A function template declaration is just a function declaration preceded by `template<...>`. From the declarator in that function declaration you extract a parameter-type-list; that's the parameter-type-list of the function template. I'm not even seeing where you get the idea that deduction is involved.

Comment: How can you not?  It states right in the document you linked to, and I quoted it to you, `After producing the list of parameter types...forming the function type. The resulting list...is the function's parameter-type-list`.  If you don't have the parameter type list, how can you even suggest that two functions are of the same type, when you don't know what the types of the parameters are?  That's like saying that all fruit are the same.  No, an apple is an apple and a banana is a banana.  They are not the same, and you can't know if two fruits are the same until you know what fruit you have.

Comment: @Adrian Of course you can compare function templates without substituting in a concrete type. The parameter type is simply something like "the first template parameter". How else do you match out-of-class definition of member function templates to their declaration? (Not to mention that, after deduction and substitution there are no function parameter packs left, so according to your argument the part about function parameter packs you happily omitted is nonsensical.)

Comment: Regardless, I'm done here. Deduction doesn't affect name lookup. That's such a fundamental part of C++'s design that if any text in the standard were to suggest otherwise, that would be nothing more than a defect in the standard. You can lawyer this to your heart's content if you want; it won't change anything.

Comment: Don't be facetious.  I didn't happily omit anything.  That would, of course, be a special case, as parameter packs are of a type unto their own.   A placeholder, that wouldn't benefit from trying to try and expand it as that would be part of the template signature.  I didn't write the standard, I only am pointing to it.  Doing the hiding at step 1 as opposed to after 2 not only contradicts what it says, but also makes coding for the programmer more complex and less elegant.

Comment: There is no such thing as a parameter pack after substitution, and there is no contradiction except in your imagination. If you want to insist on a torturous, self-inconsistent reading of the language of the standard that nobody else agrees with, it's your loss, not mine. Feel free to implement your own "Adrian-C++" compiler, since no sane compiler implementer will be doing stuff your way.

Comment: Wow... Your composure is incredible.  Just because something isn't done one way, doesn't automatically make doing it that way make someone not sane.